# SCSS nesting is looking for a child

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass, compass

I'm having an issue with SCSS, which is probably just down to inexperience. I'm trying to make my `stylesheet.scss` file give a style for any image with a certain class, and then have more styles based on other classes, like below

SCSS:

```
img.postimage {
  height: 150px;

  .expand {
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    &:hover {
      transform: scale(1.1);
    }
  }
}
```

The annoying thing is, this doesn't compile CSS like below:

```
img.postimage {
  height: 150px;
}

img.postimage.expand {
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}

img.postimage.expand:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

It actually generates it like this:

```
img.postimage {
  height: 150px;
}

image.postimage .expand { /* note the space, it's actually looking for a .expand child */
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}

image.postimage .expand:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

I'm not great at SCSS, so I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the ampersand to fix this

e.g.

```
image {
   &.someclass {
      margin:10px;
   }
}
```

would become

```
image.someclass {
   margin: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Ah great thank you. I've just tested on Sassmeister and it's all good now. I'll accept ASAP!

Comment: No problem, I think everyone who starts with Sass had this question, including myself.

Comment: I should have really thought of it tbh, because I also struggled with the pseudoclasses (`:hover` etc.)